# How to sort spark dataframe on the combination of columns in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame in Java, something like below:

[image]

I want it to be sorted based on "Col3" but all the values of Col1 and Col2 should be in a group.
The result should be something like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The groupBy() function is used during aggregation while your requirement just requires orderBy()

Assuming dataframe df with 3 columns Col1, Col2, Col3, you can do the below in Spark

```
val sortedDf = df.orderBy(col("Col1").desc,col("Col2").desc,col("Col3").asc)
```

POC for the same is available here [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7ca02/1/0)

Comment: This was helpful, did not exactly work the way I wanted so had to take another approach.

Comment: Was it because of the approach or dataset?

Comment: It is the approach. The SQLFIDDLE you shared if you compare that with the one I have put as output in question you will get it. You are simply making col1 and col2 in descending order. But that is not what I am expecting here.